# error: The method 'onChanged' isn't defined for the type

Tags: flutter, checkbox, methods

```
Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  const ListTile(
                    title: Text('This is a task.'),
                    trailing: Checkbox(
                        value: false, onChanged: (value) => onChanged()),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

//I tried to delete onChanged but it doesn't work says OnCgange required. I am open any suggestion

Comment: What is the second `onChanged`? `onChanged: (value) => **onChanged()** // <- this one`??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know I just want to make checkbox with text, I couldn't , when I delete onChanged says it is required

Comment: I am watching flutter tutorial of Angela ti,there are many changes after flutter update I find all after searching trying but this looks easy but I can't do it , I tried too much

Comment: I can't really help you because it would take a lot of explaining how the checkbox works, but I can tell you to change the line to this: `onChanged: (value) {}`, this will compile, but it will definitely not work as expected (in fact, the checkbox won't work at all) If you want to understand how the `onChanged` callback works, you can take a look at [this page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html) or look at a tutorial

Comment: thanks anyway :), I will look again to the link that you send

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('This is a task.'),
                      trailing: Checkbox(
                        value: false,
                        onChanged: (value) => null,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

remove the cont value in front of the Listtile and modify unchanged function

Comment: It works thanks a lot :) teşekkürler :)

Comment: hic onemli degil ama +1 vermeyi unuttun galiba :)

Comment: Kusura bakma 15 reputain istiyor ben de yeniyim hiç yok, denemiştim veremiyorum

Comment: neyse ben sana vereyim o zaman :)